# Compare two input and merge the difference

Tags: diff

How can I compare two input strings and merge differences and get the result string like below with tools like diff?

e.g. When I have two strings

```
unix&linux stackoverflow unix&linux
```

and

```
UnixAndLinux stackexchange
```

I'd like to get a string

```
uUnix&AndlLinux stackoverflowexchange unix&linux
```

Comment: Why `stackoverflowexchange` but `stackoverflowxchange`. Try to explaine what you want in words.

Comment: And you say you have a couple of strings but want to use a tool "like diff".  But tools like diff work on files **not** strings.  So, what do you want?  Your explanation is completely inadequate for any possible solution.